# Scheduled task to clean a directory on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, maintenance

My Microsoft Exchange 2010 installation server suffers from disk space absence sometimes. To work around this problem I usually just go ahead and remove log files on my mailbox folder.

I have to do it every 3 months. Is it possible to set up a recurring task in Windows Server, so that it would check the size of the mailbox folder, and if it exceeds, for example 4 GB, remove all the log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ye, and it is trivial (beginner sysadmin level). Sionce quite some time Windows Server has a task scheduler that can start any program or script locally. Create script, create task to run script regularly, finished.

OR, if you are aa little more professional: Use your System Center Operations Module to run a regular mainteannce script on the machine.

Comment: Thanks TomTom. A script like PowerShell script?

Comment: For example. I actually would use powershell these days ;) Frist I would write a sciptr to manually execute, then automate the execution - but I would use system center. I do not like to track dozens of scripts on different machines.

Comment: For me, being a .net developer, it turns out to be easier to just write an executable that does all the work based on a logic, then to learn an debug the PS script =)

Comment: Same here, but then I would rather write a scriopt. It IS the new world of Powershell and I move to wards maykin my software usabble via powershell anyway.

Comment: Yes, good point! PowerGUI tools makes writing scripts much easier, from what I can tell now.